# Global variable is not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, variables, global-variables

In my view controller's main file, I created a property for an NSArray object named `finalStringsArray`:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *finalStringsArray;`

Then in viewDidLoad, I make sure to initialize the object:

```
self.finalStringsArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Further down the viewDidLoad method implementation, I query my server for data, get rid of some of the extra junk that the server sends me like blank space, and then I place my perfect strings inside of my `finalStringsArray` array:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

     NSString *parseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", objects];


     NSString *cURL=[self stringBetweenString:@"=" andString:@")" withstring:parseString];


     NSString *newString = [cURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

     NSString *newString2 = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];

     NSString *newString3 = [newString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];


        _finalStringsArray = [newString3 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


        int index;

        for(index = 0; index < _finalStringsArray.count; index++) {

            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]init];


            string = _finalStringsArray[index];


            NSLog(@"Count: %d", _finalStringsArray.count);

        }

        NSLog(@"Count: %d", _finalStringsArray.count);


    } }


 ];}
```

All that matters in the above code is this statement: `_finalStringsArray = [newString3 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`

This adds my finalized strings to my `_finalStringsArray` array object. You will notice that I am NSLogging the count property of my array: `NSLog(@"Count: %d", _finalStringsArray.count);`

When I perform these NSLogs, they always NSLog with the correct count of 2.

Here's my problem though. Further down, I have a method implementation that needs to use the count property of `_finalStringsArray` as well. But for some reason, it always NSLogs as "0" and I can't figure out why.

Below are the 3 method implementations that are below my viewDidLoad. I need to be able to access the count property of `_finalStringsArray` in the method implementation for 
`-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    NSLog(@"all good string count3: %d", _finalParseStrings.count);

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1 ;

}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"all good string count5: %d", [self.finalStringsArray count]);


    return [self.finalStringsArray count];


}
```

Comment: There's a hell of a lot to be said for simply not using globals (particularly when you're just starting out).  Simply, learn to use singletons. After all, the Application is a singleton, its' a good simple place to keep one or two "globally needed" concepts.  All you have to do is add a property to AppDelegate.h - and then use it anywhere you want.  Couldn't be easier.  You can include a handy macro in your Prefix file: **#define APP ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` is an *asynchronous* method. Probably 
`numberOfRowsInSection:` is called *before* the completion block has been called
and assigned a new array.

You probably should call `[self.tableView reloadData]` at the end of the completion
block to update the table view with the fetched data.

I don't know if `PFQuery` calls the completion block on the main thread.
If not then you have to dispatch the data source assignment and the `reloadData` call to the main queue.

Comment: that did it! Thank you very much for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the proper setter & getter for that property that you declared.

I bet if you change this line:

```
    _finalStringsArray = [newString3 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

to this:

```
    self.finalStringsArray = [newString3 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

in your block function, you might have better luck.

Comment: I was hoping your solution would work but it's not. It's still NSLogging with a count of 0. As self.finalStringsArray and _finalStringsArray. And I've tried the count method and the count property. Any other ideas?